# Change Apache server port dynamically (not manually, through programmatically)

Tags: port, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I have installed Apache 2.4 in windows successfully, It is working.

Now I want to change the listening port dynamically (Not manually. meant to say, open a file and edit the port), might be place any properties file and read port from this or passing port as parameter to hhtpd.exe while starting server. Ultimately I have to configure port externally.

Answer (score 0):

not possible. Use a script that changes it and gracefully restarts the server, or you won't be able to do it otherwise.